# NaN error in my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i did this with help cause i am  not experienced in jquery

```
var fullDate = new Date(data[0].date);
                var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);
                var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + fullDate.getFullYear();
```

`"<td class='col-md-4'>"+currentDate+"</td>"+`

to format the date i work with and in localhost worked great ,but at the server give me NaN errors everything else in the code works great also if i refresh my php code works great too any suggestions ?

Comment: Why not to add an if condition like if(data[0] && data[0].date)

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be in:

```
new Date("data[0].date");
```

In this case, you are passing the string `data[0].date` to the `Date()` function, which probably return **NaN**, because `data[0].date` is not valid Date format.

Try to edit your `Date()` input to:

```
new Date(data[0].date);
```

In the code above, you will post the value of `data[0].date` to a Date function, instead of string.

Comment: oups my copy paste was wrong sorry but it was in strings *

Comment: @jProgrammer and can you post the value of  `data[0].date` ?